# Regular expression to exclude 0 or blank space

Tags: regex

```
^[0 ]{1}\Z
```

I'm looking for a regular expression that targets 0 and a single blank space

This isn't working... what am I doing wrong?

It searches for any instance of 0 in a string. I don't want it to do that. I want it to ONLY find instances where the field has a '0' or if it is left blank.

```
10 <--- grabs 0 (should not do this)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs

Comment: avoid 0 or blank = [^0 ]

Comment: what language are you targeting? Not all regexp is the same. Also what is the use case?

Comment: Please try `^(0| )$`

Comment: I'd suggest you to update your post, include sample text covering both cases. What you want to be matched and what not. Also clearly mention if you are using regex in any programming environment or particular text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will check if there's only one occurrence of the character '0' or ' ' and they are the only character provided.

```
/^([0 ])$/
```